# Can I query an XML tag without specifying it's parent tags in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have table column that stores the outgoing XML of an API service. I need to search for all records where for example:

```
<personId>1</personId>
```

The problem is the parent tags are inconsistent, as they come from different transactions such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
    <personId>1</personId>
</order>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<query>
    <personId>1</personId>
</query>
```

Typically, I'd query xml the following way:

```
where xmlValue.value('(order/personId)[1]', 'int') = 1
```

Is there a way to query the xml values without specifying the parent tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "personId" does not occur anywhere else you might go the easy way with

```
where xmlValue.value('(//personId)[1]', 'int') = 1
```

To try it out:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,xmlCol XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
    <personId>1</personId>
</order>')
,(2,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<query>
    <personId>2</personId>
</query>');
```

If you do not know where in your XML-tree a node is situated you might use the double slash "//"

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE xmlCol.value('(//personId)[1]','int')=2
```

If you know the level, but the parent name is different, you might use the Asterisk

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE xmlCol.value('(/*/personId)[1]','int')=1
```